# Setting Expire header only for Images used in css file

Tags: css, caching, web

On my webpage I want to use Expire header only only my Layout images like, background-images, buttons tabd but not on the other images like product images, sliders etc

Comment: How do you (programmatically) know if an image is a frill or content?

Comment: Easiest way to go: Put those images in a separate folder, and activate Expires for that folder only.

Comment: How I will implatemt this? I mean folder based Expires